# Time complexity: do these two codes have the same time complexity or not?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I'm reading a book called *cracking the coding interview* 6th edition. With regards to **time complexity**, there's an example code for Recursive Runtimes (page 44):

```
int f(int n) {
 if (n <= 1){
  return 1;
 }
 return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1);
}
```

**I am thinking if the following code which produces the same numeric result would have the same time complexity? I guess it would not?**

```
   int f(int n) {
     if (n <= 1){
      return 1;
     }
     return 2 * f(n - 1);
    }
```

*additional: the following is the context of the (first) code in the book:*
[image]

Comment: Can you give that book details?

Comment: Check https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g(n)%3Dg(n-1)%2Bg(n-1)

Answer (score 2):

**Executing** a function twice is not the same as multiplying the value of function at that point with 2. Think of a function execution as a couple of instructions being executed.

So when you do:

```
 return f(n-1) + f(n-1) //In your definition of f(n)
```

To compute `f(n)`, `f(n-1)` needs to be computed twice. And then to compute `f(n-1)`, `f(n-2)` needs to be computed twice in turn. So the execution calls grow in form of a tree, multiplying twice at every level. Looks something like this in pictorial format:

[image: Multiple recursive calls]

However, in your second definition where:

```
return 2 * f(n-1) //In your definition of f(n)
```

To compute `f(n)`, we compute `f(n-1)` **once** only and then we just multiply it with 2 which does not affect the overall complexity of the program in terms of the number `n`. Notice that we are not saving intermediate values of `f(n-1)` or `f(n-2)` anywhere and that's why I say they are computed every time, otherwise the scenario would have been different.So in your case, the program progresses something like :

[image: Linear recursion]

Try and go through your function definitions again and visualize them in terms of instructions getting executed at every iteration. You'll arrive at two similar pictures in your mind.

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: `graphviz` may be your friend to easily visualize any kind of tree structure in no time